# Why is my computer using a lot of swap memory?

Tags: ubuntu, swap

My computer has been freezing quite a few times over the last few months.
I was initially using
`Ubuntu 18.04`. I then upgraded to `Ubuntu 19.04` and now I am finally on `Ubuntu 20.04`. And slowly it has been freezing less and less, but still freezes at least 4-5 times a week.

Now I know other people using `Ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04` but don't see this problem occurring on their computer.

With just the terminal running on my computer, I have just 40MB of free swap memory from a total of 980MB allocated to it.

```
root@mycomp:~# free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          7.6Gi       1.8Gi       3.3Gi       432Mi       2.6Gi       5.2Gi
Swap:         979Mi       937Mi        42Mi
```

What I want to know is, why does this happen? And if it does happen how to solve this issue? I can allocate more swap memory to the computer, but I really want to figure out why its using this much in the first place.

These are my system specifications if it is helpful to anyone:

[image]

Comment: Try using `top` or `htop`. Use F6 to sort by memory usage and that will tell you which process is using all of that memory.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to allocate more swap. Ubuntu defines when to use swap with an attribute called 'swappiness', which is set to 60 by default. So, it begins using swap when your RAM only 60% left. You need to change this value to 10, so that your system begins using swap only when RAM usage reaches 90%. Do this:
`sudo nano /etc/sysctl.conf`. In the end, append `vm.swappiness=10`.
Now, to activate changes, `sudo sysctl -p`.
Then reboot. (You can use lower settings, too, like 5, but 10 is recommended)